# Extract multidemensional array string

Tags: php

I have multidimensional array string stored in PHP variable and I want to extract the keys and its values. Below is the given string which need to be split.

```
 [{"cutoffTime":"1","refundInPercentage":"50"},
  {"cutoffTime":‌​"3","refundInPercent‌​age":"70"},
  {"cutoffT‌​ime":"6","refundInPe‌​rcentage":"90"}
 ]
```

How can I extract this?

Answer (score -1):

Try this to have your work done

```
json_decode($string)
```